# Como instalar a bliblioteca freeglut no dev c++?

Tags: c, c++, dev-c++, lib

Alguem pode me ajudar? Como eu faço para instalar a biblioteca freeglut no devc++? Semestre que vem vai ter computação gráfica na faculdade e eu não consigo instalar a biblioteca freeglut para me ajudar no desenvolvimento dos jogos.

O que eu tenho até agora é uma pasta chamada freeglut dentro dela tem

Uma pasta chamada Bin, outra Include e Outra chamada Lib

Dentro da pasta bin tem o arquivo freeglut.dll
Dentro da pasta include tem os arquivos freeglut.h glut.h freeglut_std.h freeglud_ext.h
Dentro da pasta lib tem dois arquivos libfreeglut.a e libfreeglut_static.a

Alguem pode me ajudar ? não tenho noção de como instalar e toda vez que tento da errado.

Answer (score 1):

Resposta retirada de [uma discussão](https://sourceforge.net/p/dev-cpp/discussion/128327/thread/1baf9670/#eb92) da página do Dev-C++:

> 1) clique nos Projetos -> "Opções do Projeto" -> "Parâmetros"
>
> 2) em "Linker", onde diz: "Adicionar biblioteca ou objeto",  clique
>   nesse botão,
>
> 3) varrer a lista até encontrar a biblioteca que deseja vincular,  (**
>   se sua_biblioteca.a não estiver na pasta / lib / padrão, selecione a  pasta
>   correta ),  clique duas vezes nela,  que colocará libcurl. na lista de
>   linkers,  repita o processo para mais bibliotecas,
>
> 4) clique no botão OK para fechar a janela,  5) Em FILE, clique em
>   "Save All",  6) Em Execute, clique em "Rebuild All"

**Conselhos**

Pessoalmente eu recomendaria o [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) para este tipo de projeto, por ser possível criar a janela e a partir dela já implementar o OpenGL, DirectX e [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) , ou seja, facilita bastante se você em algum momento fazer que seu jogo/aplicação suporte múltiplas APIs gráficas.

Você mencionou desenvolvimento de jogos, então eu recomendaria a [Unreal Engine 4](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/what-is-unreal-engine-4) para seus projetos futuros, ela tem suporte a diferentes plataformas (inclusive televisores) e apis gráficas, ela tem jogos consagrados no seu currículo como street fighter e o remake do final fantasy VII que estar em produção.

Comment: Pensei que a Unreal não tivesse versão para estudante. Agora vi no "about": use de graça, pague 5% ao despachar

Comment: Não me ajudou muito amigo !! Seu tenho a glut.h a glut32dll e a glut.lib eu adicionei a lib e agora ?

Comment: Bom, você vai precisar basicamente do cabeçalho, da biblioteca.a do glut e do arquivo.dll que deve ser posto no diretório de execução do seu programa, como você esta usando glut suponho que seu projeto va usar opengl, então você deverá adicionar o parâmetro de linkagem do opengl32, porém não faço idéia como se faz isso no devc++

Comment: Essa página da Microsoft explica sobre o uso de dlls https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/1ez7dh12.aspx seria uma boa se você usasse o visual studio community nos seus projetos

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, ultimamente ela esta sendo considerada a rainha dos indies, pois você tem uma engine AAA e só paga 5% dos seus lucros, e a cada dia ela melhora, recentemente ela integrou o simplygon completamente no seu editor permitindo o uso gratuito para otimização de malhas