# Como instalar o libcurl no Dev c++?

Tags: c, dev-c++

Tentei instalar aqui mas o seguinte código não compila:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main( void )
{
   int a = 1, b, c;
   char post[1000];
   CURL *curl;
   CURLcode res;

   /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
   curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );

   /* get a curl handle */
   curl = curl_easy_init();
   if ( curl ) {
      // aqui é definido o formulario que recebera os dados da requisição (POST).
      curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1/triangulo.php" );

      while ( a > 0 ) {
         printf( "\nDigite os 3 lados do triangulo separados por espaco: " );
         scanf( "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c );

         sprintf( post, "n1=%d&n2=%d&n3=%d", a, b, c ); //Aqui é definida as variaveis do POST

         curl_easy_setopt( curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, post );

         /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
         res = curl_easy_perform( curl );

         if ( res != CURLE_OK ) // verifica se deu algum erro
            fprintf( stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror( res ) );

      }

      /* always cleanup */
      curl_easy_cleanup( curl );
   }
   curl_global_cleanup();
   return 0;
}
```

Erros apontados pelo compilador:

> main.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_global_init' main.c:(.text+0xe5): undefined reference to` __imp_curl_easy_init'
> main.c:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_setopt' main.c:(.text+0x1b9): undefined reference to` __imp_curl_easy_setopt'
> main.c:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `__imp_curl_easy_perform' main.c:(.text+0x1ec): undefined reference to` __imp_curl_easy_strerror' main.c:(.text+0x22f): undefined reference
> to `__imp_curl_easy_cleanup' main.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to` __imp_curl_global_cleanup' [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu instalei a libcurl:

Simplesmente copiei o que estava na lib dele e colei na lib do Dev C++, copiei o que estava nas includes, e também joguei tudo os arquivos nas includes do Dev C++. Deixei a imagem acima pra vocês terem uma ideia. Será que instalei direito? Porque está dando esses erros? Já testei com mais de um código de exemplo e sempre acontecem os mesmos erros, não sei mais o que fazer ou tentar... já reinstalei o programa várias vezes para repetir o processo de instalação de formas diferente e sempre dá os mesmos erros na hora de compilar...

Comment: Vc está linkando a biblioteca? Acredito que seja `-lcurl`

Comment: Não... nem sei fazer isso, pode me dar um exemplo? Onde eu digito isso?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309433/como-instalar-a-bliblioteca-freeglut-no-dev-c
Essa resposta tem um passo a passo que pode ser útil.

Comment: Não funcionou, fui até a pasta do arquivo curl.h e mesmo assim dá os mesmos erros

Comment: Ah tá. Tô vendo no seu screenshot que a sua pasta da curl-7.72.0 é o código fonte e não os binários. Vc compilou a biblioteca? No caso como vc está usando o MinGW-w64 vc vai precisar compilar os arquivos .a e instalar eles na pasta lib, .dll na pasta bin e copiar os cabeçalhos da pasta include de curl para a pasta include do compilador. É meio complicado instalar bibliotecas em C/C++, se continuar tendo dificuldades talvez seja melhor vc buscar um package manager como o `vcpkg` ou `conan.io`.

Comment: Eu achei uma pasta chamada libcurl que eu ainda não tinha visto, nela tem todos esses arquivos que o compilador acusa erro, onde será que eu tenho que jogar essa pasta libcurl?

Comment: Quais arquivos?

Comment: Os arquivos do erro do compilador, por exemplo: main.c:(.text+0xdc): undefined reference to __imp_curl_global_init' dai nessa pasta tem um arquivo com esse nome só que com extensão .3 mas acho q não deve ser nada...

Comment: Tente instalar os arquivos que estão nesse link. Não tenho o MinGW-w64 para testar aqui, mas no site está escrito que compilaram a biblioteca com ele. https://curl.haxx.se/windows/dl-7.72.0_2/curl-7.72.0_2-win64-mingw.zip